# How can i show more than 1 image in my map using my function (google maps)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

This is my first question here so please be cool with me. I'm trying to use add more than only one image to my markers using this code. Everything is alright but when I display the info all m y markers are the same image instead of the one they have on my BD. I guess it's because my loc.marker but I really do not get it. If someone can give me a hand i will be grateful

Here is my function:

```
function setMarkers(locObj) {
    <?php for ($i=0; $i<count($plak); $i++) { ?>
    $.each(locObj, function(key, loc) {
        if (!locations[key] && loc.lat !== undefined && loc.lng !== undefined) {
            loc.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng),
                map: map,
                icon: 'profile/img/<?php echo $carr[$i] ?>.png'
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(loc.marker, 'click', (function(key) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[key].info);
                    infowindow.open(map, locations[key].marker);
                }
            })(key));
            locations[key] = loc;
        } else if (locations[key] && loc.remove) {
            if (locations[key].marker) {
                locations[key].marker.setMap(null);
            }
            delete locations[key];
        } else if (locations[key]) {
            $.extend(locations[key], loc);
            if (loc.lat !== undefined && loc.lng !== undefined) {
                locations[key].marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng));
            }
        }
    });
    <?php } ?>
}
```

I add that `for` because the `$plak` brings to me a number of registers that will be display and `$carr[]` is an array that brings to me all images name in order to place them in the markers and in the map.

**UPDATE**
I did it, just added the images into an ajax file so i just call `icon:icon.images`, delete the `for` and it shows me what I want. Thanks for everything

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that generate n times generate same code in PHP, Have you ever looked your page source code? When you looked it then understand what I am saying hence you see same images on marker, I try to present your function code below

```
$plak has these values 1-A, 2-B, 3-C
function setMarkers(locObj) {
$.each(locObj, function(key, loc) {
    if (!locations[key] && loc.lat !== undefined && loc.lng !== undefined) {
        loc.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng),
            map: map,
            icon: 'profile/img/A.png'
        });
......
    $.each(locObj, function(key, loc) {
    if (!locations[key] && loc.lat !== undefined && loc.lng !== undefined) {
        loc.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng),
            map: map,
            icon: 'profile/img/B.png'
        });
......
    $.each(locObj, function(key, loc) {
    if (!locations[key] && loc.lat !== undefined && loc.lng !== undefined) {
        loc.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng),
            map: map,
            icon: 'profile/img/C.png'
        });
......
}
```

then C marker images override other marker images in same place.
Enjoy

Comment: alright, let me see if I understood. I have to find the way to iterate that part from $.each until the {);  ? The thing is when I iterate that i can see the page source when it says every image name but the page still blank and it says that  I am missing a } . But thanks, actually you give me a great idea let me see if it works, Thank you

Comment: I think you should match icon and locobj when you in loop via locobj then could be get car icon